# how to use *ngFor for table in child component angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to display a **table** of users so:
I must put `<tr>` tag in loop **(*ngFor)**

**UserComponent.html** :

```
<div class="theme-2">
  <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <app-user *ngFor="let user of users" [user]="user"></app-user>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **UserComponent.html** :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Created_at</th>
        <th>Updated_at</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.updated_at }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the result !
[image]

> All of Table Tags got into the *ngFor , how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Move the table wrapper/header tags out of the child component. You only need to `*ngFor` on the row itself.

Comment: Presumably one of your examples is mislabeled they can't both be `UserComponent.html`. 

The precise syntax here doesn't look right to me, perhaps it's a version thing but the iteration has to be in the component (in the second `<tr>`), not in the use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*ngFor` goes on the table, not the component itself. Right now you are creating a lot of copies of the `app-user` component, which is not what you want.

```
<app-user [users]="users"></app-user>
```

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Created_at</th>
        <th>Updated_at</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.updated_at }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: well i tried it , but <tr *ngFor="let user of users"> not work (no action ! ) why ?

Comment: Typo in the answer sorry, try again